# Ошибка при старте Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

После установки русского языка в Eclipse, начала выскакивать ошибка:

```
Возникла ошибка. Просмотрите файл протокола /home/zeiris/Документы/.metadata/.log.
```

Вот сам лог: http://pastebin.com/KxmaswJ0

Русский устанавливал через http://download.eclipse.org/technology/babel/update-site/R0.13.0/mars

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Уточняю точнейший ответ Дмитрия более подробно.

1. Убрать из Eclipse Mars надстройки Papirus, для чего Help/About Eclipse/Installation Defails и сделать Uninstall для Papirus UML и потом для Papirus UML RealTime
2. Русифицировать Eclipce (этот вопрос в инете описан подробно)
3. Запускать Eclipse с помощью bat файла содержащего одну строку eclipse -nl -ru Проверено , работает.

Answer (score 1):

Не уверен, из логов не чего нормального выяснить не удалось. Но что-то похожее встречается после установки **babel** когда забываешь указать в аргументах язык локализации. В вашем случаи это *-nl ru*